# If $\{A, B, C\}$, $\{X, Y, Z\}$, and $\{A + B + C, X + Y + Z\}$ are independent random variables, are $\{A, B, C, X, Y, Z\}$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory

Let {A,B,C} be independent random variables and let {X,Y,Z} be independent random variables. Given that A+B+C and X+Y+Z are independent, is {A,B,C,X,Y,Z} independent? How do I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For a counterexample, consider $A$ and $B$ standard i.i.d. normal, $X=A$, $Y=-B$, and $C=Z=0$. Then:

- $\{A,B,C\}=\{A,B,0\}$ is independent
- $\{X,Y,Z\}=\{A,-B,0\}$ is independent
- $\{A+B+C,X+Y+Z\}=\{A+B,A-B\}$ is independent
- $\{A,B,C,X,Y,Z\}$ is not independent since $B+Y=0$ with $B$ and $Y$ being nondegenerate